# php preg_match, matching when 2 words might come in random sequence

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Is it possible to match two words that might come in random sequences?
Examples:

```
$title = "2 pcs watch for couple";
$title = "couple watch 2 pcs";
```

Currently I'm using two regexes:

```
if (preg_match("/2( )?pcs/i", $title) and preg_match("/couple/i", $title))
```

Just want to know if it can be done with only 1?

Comment: Why does it need to be a regex?

Comment: Also, the first string does not match "couple" as a whole word. Is the example good?

Comment: are you saying i cannot match both with one regex, i need to use 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just testing for the presence of the two words in the string you could use

```
'/couple.*2 pcs|2 pcs.*couple/'
```

Answer (score 1):

use strpos()

```
if(strpos($string, '2 pcs') !== False){
 //its found
}
```

or matching at first and at end

```
if(preg_match("/(^(2 pcs|couples)|(2 pcs|couples)$)/", '2 pcs watch for couples')){
//echo "found";
}
```

or

Matching anywhere:

```
if(preg_match("/(2 pcs|couples)/", '2 pcs watch for couples')){
//echo "found";
}
```

Comment: @SamDufel what do you mean more efficient? i think
`if(preg_match('/couple.*2( )?pcs|2( )?pcs.*couple/', $string))` looks better than 
`if((stripos($title, '2 pcs') or stripos($title, '2pcs')) and stripos($title, 'couple'))`

Comment: @KristianRafteseth - regular expression matching takes substantially more processing power than basic string matches.